Is it true that if the path $a \to b \to c$ is optimal, then the path $a \to b$ is optimal?
Suppose that the path $a \to b \to c$ from vertex $a$ to vertex $c$ on a directed acyclic graph is optimal. Then, is the path $a \to b$ necessarily the optimal path from vertex $a$ to vertex $b$? I think that the answer is "no", but I cannot find the problem with the following proof that the answer is "yes", so I'm curious to know of any flaws in this proof.
Suppose that the path $a \to b \to c$ is optimal and that, for the sake of contradiction, the path $a \to b$ is not optimal, such that there exists a different path $p$, with associated cost $J_p$, from $a$ to $b$ with $J_p < J_{ab}$, where $J_{ab}$ is the cost associated with the path $a \to b$. Then, if we let $J_{bc}$ be the cost of the path $b \to c$, we have that
$$
\begin{align}
J_p < J_{ab} \implies J_p + J_{bc} < J_{ab} + J_{bc}
\end{align}
$$
Because the cost $J_{ab} + J_{bc}$ is associated with the optimal path $a \to b \to c$, then there cannot be a lower cost than this. Hence, the inequality $J_p + J_{bc} < J_{ab} + J_{bc}$ is a contradiction, and so $a \to b$ must be the optimal path from $a$ to $b$.
Again, I'm not sure where I'm going wrong with this proof, so would appreciate any feedback.

It depends a bit what you mean by "a path is optimal". If you mean something like "it has the minimal total cost" (where total cost of a path is computed as the some of the costs of its edges), then your proof is correct in case all edge costs are non-negative. It is not correct, if edge-costs can be negative (but paths must be simple).

You think the answer is "no", but then you give us a proof that the answer is "yes"? Make up your mind! (By the way, the answer is "yes", as your proof clearly shows.)

What kind of cost are you considering? A time invariant cost?

@GraffL thanks. The reason I ask is because I’m aware that Bellman’s principle of optimality states that if $a \to b \to c$ is optimal, then $b \to c$ is optimal. I was wondering if the same applies to $a \to b$, which seems to be true then.

@KwinvanderVeen yes, the cost is time-invariant.

@TonyK the reason I was asking is because I’m aware that Bellman’s principle of optimality states that if $a \to b \to c$ is optimal, then $b \to c$ is optimal. I was wondering if the same applies to $a \to b$, which seems to be true then.

Bellman's principle works for any subpath, i.e. if  $a \to b \to c \to d$ is optimal, so is $b \to c$ (under the restrictions mentioned above, by the same proof you gave above)

@GraffL interesting, I didn’t know this. Out of curiosity, why does this proof break down if the costs can be negative?

If by "path" you mean "simple path" (not containing any edges/nodes twice), you have to show that the paths constructed in the proof are such simple paths (or contain a simple subpath of at most that cost).
If you try to write down that part of the proof, you will notice that this works when the costs are non-negative but not otherwise.
